# Intel HD 3000 'Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later.' Ubuntu 12.04 Kernel 3.5

Tags: mesa

I have a Core i5 with an Intel HD 3000, and i use Ubuntu 12.04 x64 with kernel 3.5.0-18, and PPA xorg-edgers for video drivers.

And i think after last update, apps are crashing a lot:

VLC won't play videos, Minecraft won't run, Netflix with modified wine won't run either.

Even glxinfo or glxgears won't run.

Here's the console output:

glxinfo

```
name of display: :0.0
Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later.
glxinfo: ../../../../../src/mesa/main/context.c:1545: _mesa_make_current: Assertion `newCtx->Version > 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

glxgears

```
Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later.
glxgears: ../../../../../src/mesa/main/context.c:1545: _mesa_make_current: Assertion `newCtx->Version > 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If you need more info, like that core dump, just tell me where to find it and i post it here.

So should i update my kernel to a newer one, wait for a driver update, or change video driver?

Comment: The same problem is reported by other people here:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147639&p=12667972

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a 3.8 kernel available for Ubuntu 12.04, it should work.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring
```

Comment: The thing is, i use VMware Workstation 9.0. Will i need to reinstall it in order to work with the new kernel?

Comment: I know almost nothing about VMware. I know that VirtualBox and many other software that require reinstallation of kernel modules at every kernel update can automate this process if `dkms` is installed. VMware should be smart enough to use dkms too, but you'll have to test it yourself.

Comment: I'm depending on VMware right now, so i can't update right now, but i accepted your answer.

Comment: Your solution is right. xorg-edgers now require at least kernel 3.6. https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa "If you are using precise on a 965 or newer intel, be sure to install linux-generic-lts-raring as mesa now requires a 3.6 kernel!"